# Problem with using compareTo with an arrayList

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist, compareto

I am trying to write a program to analyze and interpret GIS data. I have the program completely coded out but am running into issues when I try to use a compareTo to sort the program on different metrics (Elevation, Latitude, etc). I keep getting an error "The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (GISDataStructure".

The tutorials and guides I am following all have the main class adding data to the arraylist in main, whereas I am calling a different class, and using lineData to collect information from a .txt file, and looking it through, instantiating every row. I then call a method from a different class and insert the data. I currently have a basic compareTo written in my data class, where I get and set all parameters, but continuously get errors when trying different ways to use the compareTo, or even coding a basic sorting method in different classes.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GISRunner {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("GIS.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        String[] lineData = null;
        String lineRaw = null;
        String featureName, featureClass, stateCode, countyName, primaryLatitudeDMS, primaryLongitudeDMS,
                sourceLatitudeDMS, sourceLongitudeDMS, mapName;
        Integer featureId, stateId, countyId, elevationMeters, elevationFeet;
        Double primaryLatitudeDecimal, primaryLongitudeDecimal, sourceLatitudeDecimal, sourceLongitudeDecimal;

        GISDataStructure datas = new GISDataStructure();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            lineRaw = input.nextLine();
            lineData = lineRaw.split("\\|");
            featureId = 0;
            try {
                featureId = Integer.valueOf(lineData[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                featureId = Integer.valueOf(lineData[0].substring(3));
            }
            featureName = lineData[1];
            featureClass = lineData[2];
            stateCode = lineData[3];
            stateId = Integer.valueOf(lineData[4]);
            countyName = lineData[5];
            try {
                countyId = Integer.valueOf(lineData[6]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
                countyId = null;
            }
            primaryLatitudeDMS = lineData[7];
            primaryLongitudeDMS = lineData[8];
            primaryLatitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(lineData[9]);
            primaryLongitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(lineData[10]);
            sourceLatitudeDMS = lineData[11];
            sourceLongitudeDMS = lineData[12];
            try {
                sourceLatitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(lineData[13]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                sourceLatitudeDecimal = null;
            }
            try {
                sourceLongitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(lineData[14]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                sourceLongitudeDecimal = null;
            }
            try {
                elevationMeters = Integer.valueOf(lineData[15]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                elevationMeters = null;
            }
            try {
                elevationFeet = Integer.valueOf(lineData[16]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                elevationFeet = null;
            }
            mapName = lineData[17];

            GISData newGISData = new GISData(featureId, featureName, featureClass, stateCode, stateId, countyName,
                    countyId, primaryLatitudeDMS, primaryLongitudeDMS, primaryLatitudeDecimal, primaryLongitudeDecimal,
                    sourceLatitudeDMS, sourceLongitudeDMS, sourceLatitudeDecimal, sourceLongitudeDecimal,
                    elevationMeters, elevationFeet, mapName);
            datas.insert(newGISData);
        }
        System.out.println(datas.toString());
        input.close();

        Collections.sort(datas);
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

import edu.matc.itdev154.finalexam.GISData.SortByType;

public class GISDataStructure {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public ArrayList<GISData> data;

    public GISDataStructure() {
        data = new ArrayList<GISData>();
    }

    public void insert(GISData element) {
        data.add(element);
    }

    public static void searchData(ArrayList<GISData> data) {
        String state;
        GISData foundData = null;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter state code: ");
            state = sc.next();
        } while (!state.matches("^[a-zA-Z\\s]+"));

        for (GISData datas : data) {
            if(datas.getStateCode().equals(state)) {
                foundData = datas;
            }
        }
        if(foundData != null)
            foundData.toString();
        else
            System.out.println("No data found.");
    }

    public static void sort(ArrayList<GISData> data) {
        Collections.sort(
                data, (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getElevationFeet() - obj2.getElevationFeet()
                );
        data.forEach(System.out::println);

    }


    public static void edu(ArrayList<GISData> data) {
    GISData min1 = data.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(GISData::getElevationFeet))
            .get();
    System.out.println("Area min elevation feet: " + min1);

    GISData max1 = data.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(GISData::getElevationFeet))
            .get();
    System.out.println("Area max elevation feet: " + max1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder retString = new StringBuilder();
        for (GISData gis : data) {
            retString.append(gis.toString());
        }
        return retString.toString();
    }

}

/**
 * 
 */
package edu.matc.itdev154.finalexam;

import java.util.Date;

public class GISData implements Comparable<GISData> {
    public static enum SortByType {CountyName,
                                    FeatureName,
                                    PrimaryLatitude,
                                    PrimaryLongitude,
                                    SourceLatitude,
                                    SourceLongitude,
                                    ElevationFeet};

    private int featureId;
    private String featureName;
    private String featureClass;
    private String stateCode;
    private int stateId;
    private String countyName;
    private Integer countyId;
    private String primaryLatitudeDMS;
    private String primaryLongitudeDMS;
    private double primaryLatitudeDecimal;
    private double primaryLongitudeDecimal;
    private String sourceLatitudeDMS;
    private String sourceLongitudeDMS;
    private Double sourceLatitudeDecimal;
    private Double sourceLongitudeDecimal;
    private Integer elevationMeters;
    private Integer elevationFeet;
    private String mapName;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private SortByType[] sortBy;

    public GISData() {

    }
    public GISData(int featureId, String featureName, String featureClass, String stateCode, int stateId,
            String countyName, Integer countyId, String primaryLatitudeDMS, String primaryLongitudeDMS,
            double primaryLatitudeDecimal, double primaryLongitudeDecimal, String sourceLatitudeDMS, String sourceLongitudeDMS, Double sourceLatitudeDecimal,
            Double sourceLongitudeDecimal, Integer elevationMeters, Integer elevationFeet, String mapName) {
        this.featureId = featureId;
        this.featureName = featureName;
        this.featureClass = featureClass;
        this.stateCode = stateCode;
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.countyName = countyName;
        this.countyId = countyId;
        this.primaryLatitudeDMS = primaryLatitudeDMS;
        this.primaryLongitudeDMS = primaryLongitudeDMS;
        this.primaryLatitudeDecimal = primaryLatitudeDecimal;
        this.primaryLongitudeDecimal = primaryLongitudeDecimal;
        this.sourceLatitudeDMS = sourceLatitudeDMS;
        this.sourceLongitudeDMS = sourceLongitudeDMS;
        this.sourceLatitudeDecimal = sourceLatitudeDecimal;
        this.sourceLongitudeDecimal = sourceLongitudeDecimal;
        this.elevationMeters = elevationMeters;
        this.elevationFeet = elevationFeet;
        this.mapName = mapName;
    }

// Getters and Setters

@Override
    public int compareTo(GISData o) {
        return this.elevationFeet - o.elevationFeet;
    }
```

I expect the program to loop through showing the instantiation of each row of data, then another loop after my Collections.sort is called, where I would write a for each statement.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: you're trying to call `Collections.sort(datas);` but `datas` is not a `List`.

Comment: within `GISDataStructure ` you already have a `sort` method - why are you not calling that method?

Comment: You can only invoke `Collections.sort()` on a collection. A `GISDataStructure` object is not a collection.

Comment: @Scary Wombat my GISDataStructure sort method will not properly execute in main. I get a "The method sort(ArrayList<GISData>) in the type GISDataStructure is not applicable for the arguments ()" when passing no parameters.

Comment: GISDataStructure.sort(datas.data);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the GISDataStructure is not a list but rather contains a list. Because GISDataStructure  is not a list Collections.sort() cannot be called. If you want to sort the contained list, you need to reference it. In other words:

Collections.sort(datas.data);